# Background job/task monitor for Django

Tags: python, django

I have a few management commands for my Django poject that is run automatically by cron. Are there any django packages that allow me to monitor the status of my background jobs?

Currently I have to trudge through my log files to find out if everything went okay or not and I'm confident that writing a simple job/task monitor for Django wouldn't be hard all but if there were already some existing packages that you know about, it would help a lot as I don't have cobble together something myself.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used django-chronograph for managing my scheduled jobs and django-peavy for logging. That provided everything I needed.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) can be used to set up [periodic tasks](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html).

Answer (score 2):

[django-tasks](http://code.google.com/p/django-tasks/). Sorry I can't provide more info, haven't used it myself (yet), but it seems to provide what you're looking for.